# How do I correctly get data from entry boxes?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, typeerror, tkinter-entry

I've had a lot of trouble dealing with buttons and entry boxes in general, but I finally made it work. For some reason even when the code works fine, I still get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python3.10.4\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: clicker() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Your chosen Ticker Symbol is: TSLA
```

The program takes the ticker symbol from my entry box as expected, yet I still get this TypeError. How do I fix this?

Here is my full code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Stock Calculator")
root.geometry("400x400")
data = StringVar()
label1 = Label(root, text="Enter Ticker Symbol:").grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 = Label(root, text="Expected CAGR").grid(row=1, column=0)
label3 = Label(root, text="Years of Analysis").grid(row=2, column=0)
label4 = Label(root, text="Expected PE Ratio").grid(row=3, column=0)
label5 = Label(root, text="Desired Annual Return").grid(row=4, column=0)

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=data, width=5).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, sticky=W)
entry2 = Entry(root).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
entry3 = Entry(root).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
entry4 = Entry(root).grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
entry5 = Entry(root).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)


def clicker():
    print("Your chosen Ticker Symbol is:", data.get())


button1 = Button(root, text="Find", command=clicker)
button1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button1.bind("<Button-1>", clicker)

button2 = Button(root, text="Analyse").grid(row=5, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think you need `button1.bind("<Button-1>", clicker)` since you have already used `command` option of `Button`.

Comment: @aw1668 you're right, I copied both methods from YouTube haha